# Do you use the OUTER keyword when writing left/right JOINs in SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax, rdbms-agnostic

I often see people who write SQL like this:

```
SELECT * from TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON (ID1=I2)
```

I myself write simply:

```
SELECT * from TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON (ID1=I2)
```

To me the "OUTER" keyword is like line noise - it adds no additional information, just clutters the SQL. It's even optional in most RDBMS that I know. So... why do people still write it? Is it a habit? Portability? (Are your SQL's really portable anyway?) Something else that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I couldn't agree more. The OUTER keyword is just noise. Less is more.

Comment: Can we use it when we are not sure which of the table actually has the data..and we need data from any one ?

Comment: Sounds like you need `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, although it's not quite clear from your description. Maybe you need a `UNION` instead. Write a new question and describe your data and structures in detail. You'll get an answer quickly then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`OUTER` really is superfluous, as you write, since all `OUTER` joins are either `LEFT` or `RIGHT`, and reciprocally all `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins are `OUTER`.  So syntactically it's mostly noise, as you put it.  It is optional even in ISO SQL.  As for why people use it, I suppose some feel the need the insist on the join being `OUTER`, even if the left-or-right keyword already says so.  For that matter, `INNER` also is superfluous!

Comment: I asked some colleagues who use the INNER/OUTER selectors, and for them it's more an image reference; when they put OUTER, they imagine the outer part of the venn diagram. for me it was always a noise.

Answer (score 7):

**YES**

It just make things clearer in my opinion - the clearer and more obvious you state your intent, the better (especially for someone else trying to read and understand your code later on).

But that's just my opinion - it's not technically needed, so you can use it - or leave it.

Comment: +1 for "especially for someone else trying to read and understand your code later on"

Answer (score 4):

One thing that several months on Stackoverflow has shown me is how much SQL is written and / or maintained by people with no previous exposure to SQL or relational databases at all.

For that reason, I think that the more explicit you can be the better off the next programmer is going to be when looking at your code.

Answer (score 3):

No. I use

- JOIN
- LEFT JOIN
- RIGHT JOIN
- FULL OUTER JOIN
- CROSS JOIN

There is no ambiguity for me.

Comment: why not use `full join` instead of `full outer join` then?

Comment: For some reason, I ended up using the word OUTER for FULL OUTER joins only. I can't explain, it sounds better. My personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a matter of taste, I guess that people use it because they find that it leads to more readable code. For example, I prefer to use the also optional AS keyword since `SELECT ... FROM table AS t` looks more readable than `SELECT ... FROM table t` for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 'inner join', 'left join', 'right join', and 'full outer join'. 'join' without 'inner' makes it somewhat ambigious to me; 'left' and 'right' are self-descriptive and 'full' is such kind of a beast that it deserves special syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the `OUTER` keyword myself. I agree it is merely a matter of taste but omitting it strikes me as being a little sloppy but not as bad a omitting the `INNER` keyword (sloppy) or writing SQL keywords in lower case (very sloppy).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such thing as *portable SQL* in the year 2009 anyway... At some point, you need to write DBMS-specific statements (like retrieving top N rows).

I personally find the JOIN syntax redundant and instead I comma-separate table names.