# When to use the keywords INNER and OUTER in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL, and I am not understanding **the use of the keywords** `INNER` and `OUTER`.  I understand what they mean, but I don't understand when one would actually enter the keywords in a query.  It seems like a `JOIN` is always an `INNER` and a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join is always `OUTER`.

Therefore, what are the cases when one would use the keywords rather than simply writing `JOIN` (always `INNER` ?) and `LEFT JOIN` (always `OUTER` ?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: difference between inner and outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Comment: Nicely explained here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join

Comment: No - I am not asking for the difference between INNER and OUTER, I am asking in which cases do you use those keywords as opposed to simply writing `JOIN` (always `INNER` ?) and `LEFT JOIN` (always `OUTER` ?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really no functional reason for the `INNER` and `OUTER` keywords to be used, other than for clarity.

Also, not really a duplicate, but the same ground is covered by this question as well:

[Do you use the OUTER keyword when writing left/right JOINs in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741604/do-you-use-the-outer-keyword-when-writing-left-right-joins-in-sql)

Comment: Thank you for actually reading the question....  :-)  I admit it was ambiguous.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join will show all elements of the table that is defined first (on the left) plus the elements that satisfy the join condition from the second table (on the right).

If you don't define the type of join, it's considered to be an inner join.

A good explanation is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Sorry - this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: You have to define the join only if it's an outer join. By default, a join is inner join. Apart from using it in a join, I don't know the uses of inner or outer on their own tbh.

Answer (score 0):

inner is more inside the intersection and outer is "not" intersection, take a look to this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins here they explain the inner and outer, left, right, etc